# Android GridView with two colums using JSON parsing

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-json

I have a `GridView` and I'm trying to display two columns. I want to fix my image size to my `GridView`. Locally, my code was working, but when I load my JSON it the "auto fit" stops working.

The code is:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView{
public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below CustomImageView Class and you xml should be as follows

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); // This is the key that will make the height equivalent to its width
    }
}
```

And your Xml should be like this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.yourpackage.CustomImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tryied this one or text align center but text display in left algnment  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"